# Selenium Chrome Driver not able load website

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

Chromedriver is launched correctly, then start loading the page, the URL changes to 'http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/?CbSlDlH0=qGk8rqrP3bxP3bxP39Exb4.QiGYTsZaK4uvCaZ_lRVZqqDE' however the page remains blank ( white).

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\Python\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
url = 'http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it, I get redirected to the page "http://app1.nmpa.gov.cn/data_nmpa/face3/dir.html" which looks like this:

[image]

I did it with the firefox browser and geckodriver. Can you try and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Perfect. Do you have any idea why it doesn't work with chrome?

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: I haven't found any explanation on why it doesn't work with Chrome. There are many others that have this same issue. But with Firefox it works just fine